# How can I make a position:absolute; div inside a position: relative; div work in a layout centered by margin: 0 auto;?

Tags: css, css-position

I have a centered layout using `margin:0 auto;`, but one of my child divs isn't positioning itself absolutely (relative to its parent).  The page looks fine until the window is resized.  Then the child div gets pushed to the very right, and the top image (in another div) gets clipped.

What code changes do I need to make?

Here's the CSS:

```
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 display: table;
 text-align: center;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 background: #FFF url("/images/businessmanbg.jpg") no-repeat center top;
 width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
}
#container {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: left;
 position: relative;
}
#topbar {
 background: #036 url("/images/topbar.jpg") no-repeat center top;
 border:0;
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -22px;
 padding:0;
 text-indent:-9999px;
 display: block;
 height: 111px;
 width: 100%;
}
#content {
 background: url("/images/copy-bg.png");
 padding: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 900px;
 margin-top: 50px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 450px;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT (2:18 PM CDT): At someone else's suggestion, I moved the businessman background to #container, added a fixed width to #container, and added top and right positions to #content.  Looks like the positioning's ok, but the background image disappeared.  Any idea why?

The example above has been updated with the following CSS (and I deleted the wrapper DIV in the HTML):

```
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    background: url("/images/businessmanbg.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    width: 1280px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#topbar {
    background: #036 url("/images/topbar.jpg") no-repeat center top;
    border:0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding:0;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display: block;
    height: 111px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#content {
    background: url("/images/copy-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top:120px;
    right:200px;
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 3;
}
ul, li, p {
    font-size: .95em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: The image isn't appearing because you're #container and your body both have no height. As you have positioned the child elements absolutely their dimensions no longer have any effect on their parent or sibling elements. I don't think positioning is the way for you to achieve the effect you want. Check out this example - I've only looked at it in chrome but it should help: http://jsbin.com/ahike4/

Comment: Wow this is perfect!  Thanks for simplifying it by removing the positioning and just adding margin-left to #content.  Much cleaner now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know the width of the absolute positioned element you can set left:50% margin-left:-225px.

This will set the left edge of the container to the middle of its wrapper and then moves it left by half of it's own width. This will work when you know the width of the container but not that of the wrapper.

This is the only method I know of that will work. It's not terribly pretty but hope it works for you!

Comment: ahh I see, you don't want to use absolute positioning. I believe you should rethink your html. If you are wanting fluid resizing you will need to use percentages. Alternatively you can move the #topbar out of the #container, set the #container width and use margin:0 auto to center the #container. Then you can use the #content css that Vinay BR provided above

Comment: I tried to both methods: 1) percentages and 2) moving #topbar out of #container and implementing Vinay BR's #content.

The DIV still kept appearing in the wrong place.  I updated the CSS at someone else's suggestion.  See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to acheive. Your wrapper and container div's are not needed at all and try using this as you #content class

```
#content 
{
  background:url("/images/copy-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  float:right;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:left;
  width:450px;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I added your suggestions to the background, but floating right makes the DIV too far from the businessman and too close to the edge.  I'd like to keep the DIV in the same place as the image in my comment above.

I removed the wrapper div though!